# Get full address of clicked marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can you please help me out with *google maps*.

I need to get the **full address of the clicked marker and display the address details in  ASP label controls**. In fact I am showing only one marker at a time.

E.g Stand No or House Number : 15
Street Name: St Joseph Street
Suburb: Silverton
City: Johannesburg
Latitude: 24.8545
Longitude: -28.23565

I am using the following JavaScript code for the map and its working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;
    var address;

    function initialize() {

        var latitude = document.getElementById('<%= hdnLat.ClientID%>').value;
        var longitude = document.getElementById('<%= hdnLng.ClientID%>').value;

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, latitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
    }

    function toggleBounce() {

        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

I am using the following ASP controls to work with the map.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLng" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLat" runat="server" />

<div id="map-canvas" style="height:425px;"></div>

<asp:Label ID="addressStandNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressStreetName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressSuburb" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressCity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressLatitude" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressLongitude" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="addressPostalCode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I just need to get the details (the address) of the **clicked marker** on the map and assign those values to the ASP controls listed above.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the following on click event of marker

1. [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) using latlng get the location information
2. show the returned geocodig response information in asp labels. refer [geocoding response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses)

```js
//Add listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
      toggleBounce() 
      showInfo(this.position);
    });
    
    function showInfo(latlng) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
            // here assign the data to asp lables
            document.getElementById('<%=addressStandNo.ClientID %>').value = results[1].formatted_address;
          } else {
            alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```